# Redux store.getState() returning unexpected long object, possible promise issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, promise

I am trying to set up my redux store for an e-commerce style app. Our database is Firebase, and I am trying to mimic the data structure from Firebase in the redux store. I am testing it with user "likes" data first, which is structured and returned from Firebase as an Object like so:

```
Object {
  "author": "Stephen Turns",
  "condition": "Run Over By Car",
  "courseCode": "ENG540",
  "description": "A real page turner",
  "edition": "3rd",
  "id": "-MQZVV7hxTIUqXYFOxbc",
  "price": "60",
  "sellerName": "...",
  "title": "Introduction to Combustion",
  "uid": "EG4L42ZQ7qS1U8o79n2UUpHYlA02",
}
```

When my action Listeners retrieve a newly added like from Firebase, they send it off to `likesReducer` which updates my store. However, when running `console.log(store.getState())`, This is what is returned:

```
Object {
  "_persist": Object {
    "rehydrated": true,
    "version": -1,
  },
  "likesReducer": Object {
    "likes": Array [
      ChildrenNode {
        "children_": SortedMap {
          "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
          "root_": LLRBNode {
            "color": false,
            "key": "-MQZVHl3_gzSwFKpltF9",
            "left": LLRBNode {
              "color": false,
              "key": "-MQZV1mo0QQ4nktIw6wr",
              "left": LLRBEmptyNode {},
              "right": LLRBEmptyNode {},
              "value": ChildrenNode {
                "children_": SortedMap {
                  "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                  "root_": LLRBNode {
                    "color": false,
                    "key": "price",
                    "left": LLRBNode {
                      "color": true,
                      "key": "dateTime",
                      "left": LLRBNode {
                        "color": false,
                        "key": "condition",
                        "left": LLRBNode {
                          "color": false,
                          "key": "author",
                          "left": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                          "right": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                          "value": LeafNode {
                            "lazyHash_": null,
                            "priorityNode_": ChildrenNode {
                              "children_": SortedMap {
                                "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                                "root_": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                              },
                              "indexMap_": IndexMap {
                                "indexSet_": Object {
                                  ".priority": PriorityIndex {},
                                },
                                "indexes_": Object {
                                  ".priority": Object {},
                                },
                              },
                              "lazyHash_": "",
                              "priorityNode_": null,
                            },
                            "value_": "James Stewart",
                          },
                        },
                        "right": LLRBNode {
                          "color": false,
                          "key": "courseCode",
                          "left": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                          "right": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                          "value": LeafNode {
                            "lazyHash_": null,
                            "priorityNode_": ChildrenNode {
                              "children_": SortedMap {
                                "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                                "root_": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                              },
                              "indexMap_": IndexMap {
                                "indexSet_": Object {
                                  ".priority": PriorityIndex {},
                                },
                                "indexes_": Object {
                                  ".priority": Object {},
                                },
                              },
                              "lazyHash_": "",
                              "priorityNode_": null,
                            },
                            "value_": "MTH103",
                          },
                        },
"value": LeafNode {
                          "lazyHash_": null,
                          "priorityNode_": ChildrenNode {
                            "children_": SortedMap {
                              "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                              "root_": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                            },
                            "indexMap_": IndexMap {
                              "indexSet_": Object {
                                ".priority": PriorityIndex {},
                              },
                              "indexes_": Object {
                                ".priority": Object {},
                              },
                            },
                            "lazyHash_": "",
                            "priorityNode_": null,
                          },
                          "value_": "New/Like New",
                        },
                      },
                      "right": LLRBNode {
                        "color": false,
                        "key": "edition",
                        "left": LLRBNode {
                          "color": false,
                          "key": "description",
                          "left": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                          "right": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                          "value": LeafNode {
                            "lazyHash_": null,
                            "priorityNode_": ChildrenNode {
                              "children_": SortedMap {
                                "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                                "root_": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                              },
                              "indexMap_": IndexMap {
                                "indexSet_": Object {
                                  ".priority": PriorityIndex {},
                                },
                                "indexes_": Object {
                                  ".priority": Object {},
                                },
                              },
                              "lazyHash_": "",
                              "priorityNode_": null,
                            },
                            "value_": "Only used a few times - no markings at all!",
                          },
                        },
                        "right": LLRBNode {
                          "color": false,
                          "key": "id",
                          "left": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                          "right": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                          "value": LeafNode {
                            "lazyHash_": null,
                            "priorityNode_": ChildrenNode {
                              "children_": SortedMap {
                                "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                                "root_": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                              },
                              "indexMap_": IndexMap {
                                "indexSet_": Object {
                                  ".priority": PriorityIndex {},
                                },
                                "indexes_": Object {
                                  ".priority": Object {},
                                },
                              },
                              "lazyHash_": "",
                              "priorityNode_": null,
                            },
                            "value_": "-MQZV1mo0QQ4nktIw6wr",
                          },
                        },
                        "value": LeafNode {
                          "lazyHash_": null,
                          "priorityNode_": ChildrenNode {
                            "children_": SortedMap {
                              "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                              "root_": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                            },
                            "indexMap_": IndexMap {
                              "indexSet_": Object {
                                ".priority": PriorityIndex {},
                              },
                              "indexes_": Object {
                                ".priority": Object {},
                              },
                            },
                            "lazyHash_": "",
                            "priorityNode_": null,
                          },
                          "value_": "8th",
                        },
                      },"value": ChildrenNode {
                        "children_": SortedMap {
                          "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                          "root_": LLRBNode {
                            "color": false,
                            "key": "time",
                            "left": LLRBNode {
                              "color": true,
                              "key": "date",
                              "left": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                              "right": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                              "value": LeafNode {
                                "lazyHash_": null,
                                "priorityNode_": ChildrenNode {
                                  "children_": SortedMap {
                                    "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
                                    "root_": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                                  },
                                  "indexMap_": IndexMap {
                                    "indexSet_": Object {
                                      ".priority": PriorityIndex {},
                                    },
                                    "indexes_": Object {
                                      ".priority": Object {},
                                    },
                                  },
                                  "lazyHash_": "",
                                  "priorityNode_": null,
                                },
                                "value_": "001082021",
                              },
                            },
                            "right": LLRBEmptyNode {},
                            "value": LeafNode {
                              "lazyHash_": null,
                              "priorityNode_": ChildrenNode {
                                "children_": SortedMap {
                                  "comparator_": [Function NA...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)
```

I have no idea what is going on, but from earlier bugs lots of random stuff popping up like this has usually been an issue with how i have handled Promises/async issues...

Here is the code for my Action listeners and `likesReducer`:

```
//Updates local redux store with Firebase upon app startup
export function getLikesThunk() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + "/likes")
      .once("value", (snap) => {
        return snap;
      })
      .then((likes) => {
        dispatch(getLikes(likes));
      });
  };
}

//Sets up a Listener for newly added Likes on Firebase, to update the store
export function watchLikeAddedEvent(dispatch) {
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + "/likes")
    .on("child_added", (snap) => {
      dispatch(addLike(snap.val()));
    });
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  likes: [],
};
const likesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_LIKES:
      console.log(
        "                                                             GOTTEN!!!"
      );
      var l = convertObjStateToArray(action.payload);
      return { ...state, likes: l };
    case ADD_LIKE:
      console.log(action.payload);
      var l = state.likes;
      l.push(action.payload);
      console.log(
        "                                                             ADDDED!!!"
      );
      return { ...state, likes: l };
    case REMOVE_LIKE:
      var l = state.likes; //should already be an array??
      return {
        ...state,
        likes: l.filter((like) => like.id !== action.payload.id),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const convertObjStateToArray = (state) => {
  var stateObj = state;
  var stateArray = [];

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(stateObj)) {
    stateArray.push(value);
  }
  return stateArray;
};
```

Comment: `return snap` inside getLikesThunk is intentional? or should it be `return snap.val()`?

Answer (score 1):

[`LLRBEmptyNode` appears to be a Firestore object of some kind](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/collection/LLRBEmptyNode.html).  So, that matches what you said you're doing.

Note that [we strongly recommend against putting non-serializable values into the Redux store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) - you should really only save plain JS objects and arrays.

Also, your current logic has a bug in the `ADD_LIKE` case, as you're mutating the existing state.

Finally, note that you really should be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which both will simplify your Redux logic and catch common mistakes like that.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, I'm very new to this and self teaching so I had no idea what the correct way was. Ill take a look at these links!

Comment: Hi, I did a bit of reading on the links you provided, I am a bit confused on how I should go about avoiding sending a promise to update the redux store, since the data is being pulled from Firebase. Is there a best practice for this situation? I am trying to save a plain object, as shown in the OP, but my firebase Thunk returns a promise that seems to be not handled properly, I think?

Comment: Update: after logging some spots, I noticed the weird object stuff happens in my helper function ```convertObjStateToArray ```, the object is correct while passed in as ```state```, but somewhere in my for loop ```stateArray``` becomes the mess you see in my OP. Not sure whats going on, as I tested this method in isolation on a simple object and it worked fine? I'm sorry if this is an obvious mistake